# Magento from live - local server display 404 error message

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I moved the 100% working magento site from live server to my localhost.

The moving done successfully.

But there have a problem is that the home page will display correctly.

But when i clicked on other navigation menus it displays 404 not found error message.

for examle this my site link:

```
http://localhost/bc/
```

Now the site is loaded perfectly,but when i click a menu,the url is :

```
http://localhost/bc/fresh-fruit.html
```

It displays 404 not found error.

If i included the index.php in betweemn them then that page loaded correctly that is:

```
http://localhost/bc/index.php/fresh-fruit.html
```

the above link loaded the clicked page correctly.

So how can i solve this problem?

What is the real problem is here?

This is the error message displayed:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /bc/fresh-fruit.html was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like URL rewriting is not working on your localhost.  Assuming you're using Apache on your localhost, here's some things to check:

1. Check that the .htaccess file exists in your /bc folder.  .htaccess is a hidden file so it's easy to not copy it across when you copied the rest of the site (especially if using graphical tools)
2. Check that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.
3. Check that .htaccess files are enabled for the /bc folder.
4. Check that file permissions allow the apache user to read the .htaccess file (note: Apache runs as a different user to your normal login, so the fact that you might be able to read it doesn't necessarily mean Apache can.